# Linq to XML - Namespaces

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Book List</title>
</head>
<body>
<blist:books
xmlns:blist="http://www.wrox.com/books/xml">
<blist:book>
<blist:title>XSLT Programmers Reference</blist:title>
<blist:author>Michael Kay</blist:author>
</blist:book>
</blist:books>
</body>
</html>
```

from the given Xml document,I want to iterate all `<blist:books>` elements.

(i.e)
How to i handle the namespace ?

i tried

```
XNamespace blist = XNamespace.Get("http://www.wrox.com/books/xml");
XElement element = XElement.Load("Books.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> titleElement =
            from el in element.Elements(blist + "books") select el;
```

but the enumeration (titleElement) does not return any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different problems here.

1. You're calling the `Elements` method, which returns the *direct* child elements of the element you call it on.  Since the `<html>` element has no *direct* `<blist:books>` child elements, you aren't getting any results.
2. XML is case sensitive.  You need to write `books`, not `Books`.

Also, there's no point in writing `from el in whatever select el`.  Unless you put addition logic (such as a `where` or `orderby` clause, or a non-trivial `select`), you should just write `whatever`.

Therefore, you need to replace your LINQ query with the following:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> titleElement = element.Descendants(blist + "books");
```

Comment: If i suppose to use XmlTextReader (not linq to xml) how can i achieve the same result ?

Comment: It would take a lot more code.  LINQ to XML is the easiest way to handle XML in .Net _by far_.